# How to bypass ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For my HTML structure I want to load a template outside my `ng-repeat` call, but still use data from the `movie in movieGroup` call.

This template creates a `movie_container` div element for every movie in the movieGroup variable. In the `movie_container` div I have a `a` element that calls a state route `.test`.

```
.container-wrapper{"ng-repeat" => "movieGroup in movieGroups"}
  .movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieGroup | orderBy:'release_date'"}
      .movie-info
        %a{:href => "#", "ui-sref" => ".test({value: '{{ movie.movie_id }}' })"} More info

  .big-box{"ui-view" => "test"}
```

This is the `.test` state,

```
.state('home.test',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "test":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.movie = $stateParams.value
        // $scope.value = $stateParams.value;
        console.log (movie_id)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

As you can see it inserts a template called `_movie-info.html` into the `test` view from the first template.

The `_movie-info.html` template looks like this,

```
.container-info{"ng-style" => "{'background-image':'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280{{movie.backdrop}})'}"}
  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in filteredTrailers = (trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})"}
      %a{"ui-sref" => ".container-big-trailer({value: '{{ trailer.link }}' })"} Load trailer

  .container-trailers
    %div{"ui-view" => "youtube_trailer"}
```

But now I can't use things like `{{ movie.backdrop }}` or `(trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})`.

So I'm hoping there is a way to pass the data I need to my second template `movie-info.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the movie object instead of the movie_id

```
".test({value: '{{ movie}}' })"}
```

you should be able to use $scope.movie.movie_id inside your second template. Another way would be by using `$scope.$parent.movie`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I think I got it going a bit. Ive changed my `ui-sref` to pass the object `{{ movie }}` and in the controller `home.test` I've created a scope `$scope.movie = $stateParams.value` that inserts the data form the `a` click. I also `console.log ($scope.movie)` after, and it is indeed the movie object and data I want. My problem now is that I can't get the info in my template. If I do `movie title: {{ $scope.movie.title }}` or `movie title: {{ movie.title }}`  The `{{ }}` don't get rendered. So how do I use the data that I made in the `$scope.movie` in the state controller?

Comment: Can you create a plunkr for this?

Comment: Through a different question I got my answer. But thanks for the help though, got me in the right mindset.

Comment: To clarify, the `value` is just a parameter name. It can be anything. I thought it was a set parameter. Caused me some problems when I wanted to pass 2 values (in different states even).